# binarydeb with CGAL

Tags: jenkins, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem building a package using the CGAL libray on the buildfram.

The prerelease test is sucessful on both my local computer and Jenkins but I get the following error when trying to build the binary deb:

> CMake Error at> /usr/lib/CGAL/CGAL_SetupFlags.cmake:65
>
> (message):   RelWithDebInfo is not a
> valid build type: only Release or Debug is allowed

The inclusion of CGAL in my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

> find_package(CGAL REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

> set(CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_CMAKE_FLAGS TRUE CACHE BOOL "Don't override flags")

> include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})

The package name is crossing_detector. Its source is in https://github.com/lama-imr/lama_utilities/tree/indigo-devel/crossing_detector.

How can I deal with this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200929/binarydeb-with-cgal/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to reproduce this locally by using:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

Once you can do that, you can work out a solution locally before you release a new version to the farm.

My only thought about actually fixing this is to try setting the CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_BUILD_FLAGS variable *before* you call find_package(CGAL).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on 2015-01-14**:
Thanks for the answer, unfortunately setting CGAL_DONT_OVERRIDE_BUILD_FLAGS before find_package didn't help.
What I did is a workaround:
`set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")` before and `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo")` after.
I don't like to play with the build type in CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-14**:
I agree that setting the build type in your CMakeLists is not a good solution. You may want to consult the CGAL documentation or contact the CGAL developers, since it's their build files which are rejecting a standard CMake build type.